# Modperl::perlrun reload modules

Tags: perl, mod-perl

I am converting my app to run under modperl::perlrun, There are some legacy modules which create closures, Is there any way to reload Modules (.pm files ) for each request under Perlrun ?

Answer (score 0):

see http://perl.apache.org/docs/1.0/guide/porting.html#Name_collisions_with_Modules_and_libs